# Вставка картинки в поле blob

Tags: php, изображения, firebird, blob

Не получается вставить картинку в поле `blob`. Я пробую так:

```
$database   = "******";
$user       = "*****";
$ps   = "***";

$dbh = ibase_connect($database, $user, $ps, 'utf8') or die(json_encode(array('message' => 'not connection', 'successed' => false)));

$file = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];

$file_contents = file_get_contents($file);
$blob = blob_create($file_contents);
// дальше просто виснет

define('MAX_SEGMENT_SIZE', 65535);
function blob_create($data) {
   if (strlen($data) == 0)
       return false;
   $handle = ibase_blob_create();
   $len = strlen($data);
   for ($pos = 0; $pos < $len; $pos += MAX_SEGMENT_SIZE) {
       // следующая строка 772
       $buflen = ($pos + MAX_SEGMENT_SIZE > $len) ? ($len - $pos) : MAX_SEGMENT_SIZE;
       $buf = substr($data, $pos, $buflen);
       ibase_blob_add($handle, $buf);
   }
   return ibase_blob_close($handle);
}
```

В результате я получаю сообщение:

`Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/kommunal/kommunalnik.in.ua/www/query.php on line 772`

Ставил вместо 30 секунд больше (5 минут) - не памагает.

Пробовал еще так:

```
$database   = "******";
$user       = "*****";
$ps   = "***";

$dbh = ibase_connect($database, $user, $ps, 'utf8') or die(json_encode(array('message' => 'not connection', 'successed' => false)));

$file = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];

$fd = fopen($file, 'r');

$result = "";

if ($fd) {

    $blob = ibase_blob_import($dbh, $fd);
    fclose($fd);

    if (!is_string($blob)) {
        $result = "import failed";
    } else {
        // $result = $blob;
        $query = "insert into file (name, content, file_type,resource_name, identifier) values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        $prepared = ibase_prepare($dbh, $query);
        if (!ibase_execute($prepared, "123", $blob, "png",'INCOMING_MAIL',"123")) {
            $result =  "record insertion failed.Err: " . ibase_errmsg();
        } else {
            $result =  "success";
        }
    }
} else {
    $result = "unable to open the data file";
}
```

Результат:

`record insertion failed.Err:''`

Comment: Логи firebird.log смотрели?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov для чего? Я думаю что я на `php` делаю что-то не так....у меня должно сохранится в шестьнадцатиричном представлении....я не понимаю и не нахожу как это сделать. В `base64` сохранить картинку не составило труда.

Comment: Код имеет достаточно проверок, но раз вы не знаете в чём именно дело, то дополнительные проверки не помешают - в том числе и логи Firebird. Попробуйте использовать ibase_blob_info, ibase_errcode и другие вспомогательные ресурсы и функции.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov чтобы рыть вглубь ошибки, мне нужно понимать так ли все делаю...правильно ли пытаюсь записать blob, правильно ли перевожу...а я этого не понимаю ,и не нахожу как нужно.